# Как передавать одному методу класса операции из другого метода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, который нужно дополнить(по заданию)

```
class Render():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def draw_screen(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_input(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Интерфейс этого класса, помимо конструктора, состоит из четырех методов:

1. init_screen, инициализация экрана заданной высоты и ширины.
2. add_object, добавление объекта на экран. Эта функция принимает символ, который нужно нарисовать и его позицию на экране.
3. draw_screen, отрисовка экрана.
4. get_input, получение пользовательского ввода.

Необходимо завести класс ShellRenderer, который будет рисовать экран игры в консоли.

1. Заведите в нем поле _screen, которое будет представлять собой список списков символов, размера h на w.
2. Инициализируйте его пробелами при вызове метода init_screen.
3. Метод add_object должен изменять значение одного из элементов списка _screen на символ char.
4. Метод draw_screen должен выводить список на печать при помощи вызова print.
5. В методе get_input можно использовать функцию input, чтобы получить пользовательский ввод. Возвращайте введенную пользователем строку.

Я сделал практически всё, что требовалось, но у меня проблема в self._screen, туда не передаётся элемент из add_object.

```
class ShellRender(Render):
    def init_screen(self, h, w):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self._screen = ["\n".join(map(str, [self for i in range(w)])) for j in range(h)]
    def add_object(self, char, x, y):
        self.char = x, y
    def draw_screen(self):
        print(self.char)
    def get_input(self):
        return input()
```

Если  `_screen = [['*', '+', '*'], ['#', '#', '#']]`, то печатаем

```
*+*
###
```

Надеюсь на помощь в преобразовании моего кода под задание, я явно делаю что-то не так...в частности я не могу передать из одного метода элемент `char` в другой метод, ну то есть в `char` по идее будут задаваться какие-то символы по типу `*, +, *`. Но возможно я что-то ещё сделал не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы кажется путаете между собой `_screen` и `char`. Нужно как-то так:

```
def add_object(self, char, x, y):
    self._screen[y][x] = char
def draw_screen(self):
    print(self._screen)
```

И да, ещё нужно инициализировать `_screen` как список списков, а вот уже печатать его - с помощью `join` и т.д.

Comment: Изменил, да согласен с Вами, но однако мою проблему это не решило, там где-то проблема всё равно есть в ```self._screen = ["\n".join(map(str, [self for i in range(w)])) for j in range(h)]```

Comment: @Silya Дополнил ответ. Вы сделайте в `_screen` список списков, внутренний список видимо должен содержать пробел `[' ']`

Comment: @Silya Я могу и весь код написать, но это всё-таки задание, вы должны его сами как-то делать стараться

Comment: Понимаю, но проблема ещё вот в чём: как мне написать в print(self._screen) операцию с join если self."\n".join(map(str, _screen)) неправильно? Просто в голове не могу представить как сделать иначе...

Comment: буду рад, если напишите код...я уже несколько дней с этой задачей бьюсь и не понимаю как её реализовать... спасибо

Comment: @Silya А вы попробуйте ещё поделать что-то по данным мной подсказкам. Не получится - тогда посмотрим.

Comment: так мне по сути только строчку с print(self._screen) нужно заменить, вот я и понять не могу как её с join соединить, программа ругается когда я пишу self."\n".join(map(str, _screen)), но ведь по-другому же нельзя

Comment: @Silya Вам там нужен двойной цикл объединения. Сначала внутренние списки объединить, потом внешние уже через перевод строки. А можно и не объединять, просто сделать два цикла, в которых сделать печать.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то в draw_screen надо
```print("\n".join(map(str, [[self._screen for i in range(self.w)] for j in range(self.h)])))```
а до этого необходимо было сделать в init_screen
```self._screen = [[[' '] for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]```
Но так тоже не получается